# Looking for old YouTube math video - and curious about what field of statistics this is

Tags: statistics

I have been looking for a YouTube video I watched quite a while ago that I found pretty fascinating.

Suppose you had a game where you had to try and pick the largest number in a list. You only get to see the value of the next number in the list and you decide if that is the number your are going to pick, or decide to see the next number. If there are 100 numbers, how many numbers should you observe before you commit to picking the next largest number you find.  I remember that the youtube video explained that you should observe some fraction of the list and the fraction was related to e somehow.

Does anyone know what type of statistics this is or possibly a youtube video on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

I know [Numberphile](https://youtu.be/ZWib5olGbQ0) did a video on it a while back. I do not know whether that's the one you're looking for.

The solution, if your goal is to maximize the probability of finding the highest number, is that you should look through the first $1/e$ fraction of the numbers, and only after that take the first number that's higher than any other you've previously seen.

They call it the "toilet problem" in that video, but I think the more conventional name is the [*secretary problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). That ought to help you in your search for resources.

Comment: On a more informal note, the secretary situation isn't how hiring a secretary would work, while the toilet situation is at least slightly realistic. Another realistic situation where this might crop up is if you're on a highway looking for fuel refill, checking the prices on gas stations as you pass them. If you don't want to turn around and you want the lowest price possible, then this is the best approach to take.

Comment: Yes!  That is the subject I was thinking of exactly.  Thank you